# How to clear a Asp.net tree view control in javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to clear a Tree View control in javascript ? I am looking for something like treeview.nodes.clear();

Comment: if you use jQuery - take a look at the empty() method, pleasenote that TreVieew is generated as HTML table and for each Node a separate HTML <table> is generated, but you should keep in mind that server side TreeView data source will contains all items so perhaps it makes sense to do server side clean

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be *natively* possible, as interoperability is not so neatly (or not so) tied together between these technologies (ASP.NET (server-side) and Javascript); for instance, you could certainly find the element containing the items in the mark-up and clear them using Javascript, but the items would still be defined in memory on the server - and apparent during postback.

You can't even really use AJAX web method calls, since the call won't have direct access to the elements due to different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the treeview with something like treeview.nodes.clear() is something you would do server side (in your codebehind).

if you want to clear it at the client side with javascript you should acces the HTML Dom element and clear it's contents.

If you want to also clear it from say database or something you should send an ajax call with the necessary data to remove it from your database.